# Correct transliteration of foreign Names with umlauts and other diacritics

Tags: names, surnames

I would like to know how names from other languages with umlauts and other diacritics are correctly written in English **through transliteration and not translated**.

The last name `Bühler` is often written wrong with `Buhler` even though there is an alternative and correct writing without the umlaut: `Buehler`.

In German, `ü` can be replaced with `ue`, `ö` with `oe` and `ä` with `ae`. Same applies to the upper case variants of these umlauts. The German `ß` becomes `ss` (although the Swiss don't use `ß`).

How does it look with other languages such as Celtics, French, Polish, Swedish and so on? For example, how would the Swedish name `Håkan` be written in English if there is no `å`?

Umlauts and other diacritics are usually transliterated in the machine-readable part of a passport.

I would like to know how they are in other languages' names correctly transliterated to English without using diacritics. German has rules to do so, I assume other languages do too?

I understand why they are usually omitted. ;)

Comment: Mostly English writers will use the base character in place of the accented or inflected character. There are a variety of reasons for this, including ignorance of how to reproduce these characters using English equipment (eg keyboards), fear of audience reaction or inability to understand what sounds the inflected character represents, laziness, etc. Reputable institutions and careful writers will usually opt to reproduce the words or names as written in the source language. Others, especially publications, will have a “house style” which will dictate what to do; many follow either CMOS or AP

Comment: Some words (and names) have been around long enough that English cognates have been established and recorded in dictionaries; eg you’ll find that reference works license “resume” for “résumé”; the former is now considered the proper English spelling.

Comment: So, in short, expect *most* (casual) English writers to use “Hakan” in place of “Håkan”, and formal or reputable authors to use straight “Håkan”, as in Swedish.

Comment: (And please do *not* expect most English speakers to know the equivalencies ü=ue, ß=ss, etc).

Comment: Another good reason for avoiding them (especially online/in computer documents) is that the rarer diacritics or combinations of diacritics (e.g. some in Polish, Czech, or Vietnamese) will not be present in all character sets or fonts, may not display properly or consistently, and may not display at all - leaving a space, padding, or a random symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spelling issues are usually handled by style guides, so there is no single correct answer.

For example, here's what the *New York Times* style guide says (or said in 2014):

> Accent marks are used for French, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese and German words and names. For simplicity, use the marks uniformly with uppercase and lowercase letters, despite conventions that treat certain uppercase accents as optional. Do not use accents in words or names from other languages (Slavic and Scandinavian ones, for example), which are less familiar to most American writers, editors and readers; such marks would be prone to error.

[The Public Editor's Journal](https://publiceditor.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/01/16/on-times-language-use-dwarfs-indians-and-more/)

Thus, in the *New York Times*, you'd expect to see "René Descartes" but "Jons Jacob Berzelius" (rather than "Jöns").  Or for non-hypothetical example, ["What to Eat and Where to See Roman Monuments in **Nîmes**"](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/15/t-magazine/nimes-france-travel-guide.html), versus ["A labyrinth of emotions from the **Lodz** ghetto"](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/01/18/world/europe/a-labyrinth-of-emotions-from-the-lodz-ghetto.html) (not "Łódź").

Other newspapers seem to use a similar guideline, but many other publications do not.  For example:

> *AMA Manual of Style*:[...]Accent marks should always be retained in the following instances: Proper names: Dr Bönneman is a Pew Scholar in the Biomedical Sciences[...]
>
> *AP Stylebook*: "Use accent marks or other diacritical marks with names of people who request them or are widely known to use them, or if quoting directly in a language that uses them[...]"
>
> *APA style*: "[Reference list:] The best way to ensure that information is accurate and complete is to check each reference carefully against the original publication. Give special attention to spelling of proper names and of words in foreign languages, including accents or other special marks[...]"
>
> *The Chicago Manual of Style*: "Foreign words, phrases, or titles that occur in an English-language work must include any special characters that appear in the original language. Those languages that use the Latin alphabet may include letters with accents (diacritical marks), ligatures, and, in some cases, alphabetical forms that do not normally occur in English[...]"

[Wikipedia:Diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Diacritical_marks#cite_note-13)

Comment: Some names seem to have more or less standard diacritic-less versions; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nguyen) mentions that Nguyễn is normally Nguyen outside Vietnam, and many Chinese names (including those of writers or politicians) will have standard or preferred romanizations that may not match the usual pinyin or other romanization rules. But certainly consulting a style guide is a good plan; newspaper style guides will indicate standard versions of common names, and many style guides will point you to a more detailed reference.

Comment: Thank you Juhasz. This is very insightful. But with my question, I was looking for something Stuart F mentioned in his comment. I'd like to find ways to write names without diacritics but correct if there is a rule like in German.

Comment: @ThomasZuberbuehler, thank you.  I now better understand what you're looking for: some kind of English equivalent to the German ü -> ue transformation.  There are no such rules in English. I would think you'd only expect to find such rules for letters used in a particular language's alphabet.  In other words, I don't suppose German has rules for rewriting the Hungarian letters á, é, í, ó, ő, ú and ű, does it?  Likewise, since English (for the most part) does not use any letters with diacritics, it has no standardized rules for how they're used when spelling foreign words.

Comment: You are right, there are no rules on how to write Hungarian letters in German without using diacritics. But the languages themselves may have rules, like in German. I assume other countries do not randomly choose machine-readable names on passports. But I guess English Languages & Usage Stack Exchange is the wrong place to ask my question... Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @ThomasZuberbuehler, the passport question is interesting, though as you say, not one best suited for this site.  In the US, today, they seem to have a pretty hands-off approach.  When my family came to the US seventy years ago, our name was forcibly changed from the correct Hungarian *Juhász* to *Juhasz*.  On the other hand, my wife, whose original legal name is written in Persian, chose the transliteration herself when she immigrated here.

Comment: The convention that *ü* can be replaced with *ue*, and so forth, is a convention of **German** spelling; it is not really a matter of English language (although the fact that German language has that convention can make things easier for those who need to use German names in an English context). Whether some other languages have analogous conventions would thus be a question (or rather questions) about these other languages, rather than about English.